# How to load leaflet WMS layer with a CRS other than the map's CRS?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, proj4leaflet

I have a leaflet map initialized with EPSG 3857. I need to add new WMS layer that has projection EPSG 2320. I checked proj4leaflet; but I'm not sure whether a layer that has CRS different than main map's CRS can be displayed. Is it possible?

Comment: Should be, have a look at https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/examples/wms/. If that doesn't work, if possible, load the layer as WFS and then try to use L.Proj.Geojson (geojson).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have a EPSG:2320 WMS layer in a EPSG:3857 Leaflet map.

Leaflet is **not** capable of on-the-fly raster reprojection.

You can, however, use EPSG:2320 as the display projection for the whole map (which means not using EPSG:3857 at all).

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find explanation as clear as this one.